# Does copying files to live usb damage the installation?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, live-usb, persistence

I've made myself a live Ubuntu stick (with persistence if that matters)   but I can't boot into it from the PC I'm currently using (boot menu is restricted)
Can I save files onto the USB without damaging the ubuntu installation or can't I use it for anything else than booting Linux?

And are the files even kept the next time I boot Linux and are they accessible from within ubuntu??

Comment: [This older post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122832/125388) has an answer that explains on how to use the persistence filesystem `casper-rw`. For alternative method of saving and accessing the files, see [this related post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33347/125388).